# Combinatorics - how to count number of ways to distribute packages

Tags: combinatorics

Assume we have $n$  children and we want to distribute $ n $ packages, each package with a name of one children (and they have different names). I want to count for some $ 1\leq j \leq n $ in how many ways can we distribute the packages, such that $ j $ children would get the right package with their name on it, and the rest $ n-j $ children would get the wrong package.

Im not sure how to do it. Thanks in advnace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $\binom{n}{j}$ ways to choose which of the $j$ children get the correct package.

You need to multiply this by the number of ways to give the remaining $n-j$ packages to the remaining $n-j$ children such that they each get the wrong package. This is the number of [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) of $n-j$ objects, which is $(n-j)!\sum_{i=0}^{n-j}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}$.

Comment: Is it possible to calculate the sum $ \left(n-j\right)!\sum_{i=1}^{n-j}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{i}}{i!} $ explicitly?

Comment: @FreeZe I don't think there's a simpler expression for it

Answer (score 0):

It would be $\binom{n}{j}$ multiplied by the number of derangements of $n-j.$